# Using Grep and Regex to generate a text file which lists all files that have specific strings in them

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I am having trouble figuring out a very specific use case for Grep and Regex.  I have searched a lot and can't seem to find the answer.

I want to run Grep recursively from within a root directory which contains directories for hundreds of different programs.  I want the output to print to a text file and list the file names of all the files which match some regex.  Specifically, here's what I need to do in english:

find all files that contain the text [stringA] AND ["stringB"] OR ['stringB'] and print the file paths for each of these files to an output text file with some context added.  For the two stringB pieces, the quotes are important and I only want to find files that have stringB with single or double quotes around it.  In other words,

**all files that contain stringA with no quotes and stringB with either single or double quotes.**

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Edit: Sorry for asking a terrible question :)

I have done some research and have figured out part of it.  I have figured out the regex for finding the string I am looking for.  The actual string is "ATA".  To find this globally, case-insensitive, and with either type of quotes around it with some or no whitespace on either side of the string, we can use:

```
/['"]\s*ATA\s*['"]/gi
```

The first string I need to also find is a function call: call wflnkmod( and the regex for that is:

```
/call\swflnkmod\(/gi
```

Now I just need to figure out how to search a file and ensure that it has an instance of each of these in it, then figure out the grep command to use to search all files recursively and print them to an output file!

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Use `grep -l` to get a list of all files that match a regular expression. To do the `AND`, do it with the first regexp, then pipe that to `xargs` to run the second `grep -l`.

Comment: You can use `['"]` to match either single or double quotes.

Comment: Hopefully those are enough hints for you to make an attempt at doing this. If you can't get it working, edit the question with your code.

Comment: Doesn't find do most of this?

Comment: You're right, I asked a terrible question.  I did try a bunch of things before posting the question but didn't include examples because I felt like I was not on the right track.  I have updated my question with some examples of what I tried and also where my hang-up really is.  BTW, this is a real-world problem and not a homework question!  Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution

Should do the trick (`<dir>` needs to be replaced with the directory to search in):

```
grep -r -i -l "stringA" <dir> | xargs grep -i -l -E "'stringB'|\"stringB\""
```

#### Explanation

The above line searches for `stringA` first. The resulting list of files is piped into `xargs` and the specified command (`grep -i -l -E "'stringB'|\"stringB\""`) is invoked with the additional parameters provided through stdin (the list of files, that contain `stringA`).

`grep` options:

- `-r, --recursive` (self explanatory)
- `-i, --ignore-case` search case insensitive
- `-l, --files-with-matches` only print filename of files that match the 
  given pattern
- `-E` interpret pattern as extended regular expression

---

The two main issues with the expressions you've tried are:

1. Inappropriate use of `[]`. `[]` lets you define a *character set*, e.g. `[abcd]` matches one of specified characters.
2. Incorrect quoting  or escaping of quotes in your expressions. If you quote something in double quotes (`"`), double quotes inside the quoted string need to be *escaped*: `\"` yields a `"` in a quoted string. If you're not quoting your expression at all, `(` needs to be escaped as well.

Comment: Thanks!  I used what you suggested above and modified it slightly for the strings I needed to find, which were actually "call wflnkmod" and "ATA" - with either quote type.  I also wanted to allow for whitespace on either side of the "ATA" string, so my final piped grep command was:

grep -r -i -l "call wflnkmod(" 2017.1 | xargs grep -i -l -E "'\s*ATA\s*'|\"\s*ATA\s*\""

Answer (score 1):

for `AND` search it's better to chain `grep`s, `OR` can be handled.

Assume we are looking for words `cat` and `"ata"` or `'ata'`.  If you're only interested in the filenames, not the actual matches...

```
grep -wilm1 cat file* | xargs  grep -wilEm1 "'ata'|\"ata\""

file1
file2
```

searches for the full word match `-w` (not substrings), exits after first match `-m1`  and ignores cases (`-i`).  The `OR` requires `-E` flag.  `-l` prints the filenames only.

here are the files used for testing.

```
==> file1 <==
cat
fat hat "ata"

==> file2 <==
cat fat hat 'ata'

==> file3 <==
cat fat hat ata

==> file4 <==
category fat hat ata
```